# Transfer video via bluetooth(java programming)

Tags: java, bluetooth

I want to send a video file stored on pc to a mobile phone via blue-tooth. I need some help in order to know how to proceed. help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/) library. To transfer a file you must utilze the OBEX protocol.